# Sql Query for Suggestion of Friends who are friends of friends

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want retrieve friends of friends using SQL Server. Can anyone help me.

Below is my friensd table structure, in which if status is 2 it indicates friends otherwise not friends

**ID | UserID | FriendID | UserName | FriendName | RequestDate | Status | StatusUpdatedDate | IsBlocked**

Below is UserMaster Table structre

**UserId | UserName | Email | DateOfBirth | Language**

Thanks in advance

Comment: This sort of query is better addressed by using a Graph Database such as neo4j

Answer (score 0):

This query would give you friends of friends:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  f1.ID,
  f2.FriendID AS FriendOfFriendID
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      ID,
      FriendID
    FROM
      friends
    WHERE
      UserID=<LoggedInUserId> AND
      Status=2
  ) AS f1
  INNER JOIN friends AS f2 ON
    f2.ID=f1.FriendID
WHERE
  f2.Status=2;
```

---

f1 is a [derived table](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1042/using-derived-tables-to-simplify-the-sql-server-query-process/) giving you ID's of people along with their FriendID's. This is then linked to friends again (f2) to link to the FriendOfFriendID (f2.FriendID) by linking in f2 by using the FriendID of f1.

The query does a [DISTINCT selection](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187831%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to filter out equals friend-of-friends (2 of your friends might share some friends).

Comment: i want retrieve friends of friends of current logged in user

Comment: E.g If 1 is friend to 2 and 3 and 2 is friend of 4 and 5 .... 1 user should c the 4 and 5

Comment: If you have the ID of the currently logged in user, change the derived table (f1) to only select the friends of that user. Adding that to WHERE clause would give `WHERE UserID=LoggedInUserId AND Status=2`. HTH.

Comment: Hi,,, I did as u said but all values are coming thrice and also including my existing friends,,which i dont want to show tat for particular user... username and userid want to retrive from friends of friends.. Thanks in advance

Comment: The SELECT DISTINCT should filter out duplicate friends. Make sure your query is as close to what I posted.
If you don't want the query to select your friends you will have to factor that into the query. It is also not what you originally asked, I can't answer additional things you say in the comments section.